# Copy and leave out checkboxes on Repeater

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which has some controls which are checkboxes. I would like to copy all items in the repeater except the checkboxes, where in their place i will copy the value of teh checkbox. THe purpose is that I would like to export all of the information from the repeater to an excel document in xls format. However, this does not allow me to have checkboxes, thus the reason I want to remove them.

How should I do this please?

I have tried:

```
for (int j =0; j<repeater1.Items.Count; j++)
{
    RepeaterItem repItem = repeater1.Items[j];

    foreach (Control c in repItem.Controls)
    {
        if (!(c is CheckBox))
        {
            Control c2 = c;
            repeater2.Items[j].Controls.Add(c2);
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: if your item contain checkbox, you don't want to show ?

Comment: I don't want it to be part of the repeater- because then I need to export to excel and it does not accept checkboxes

Comment: Just modify your question and explain what you actually need.

Comment: Is repeater2 a separate repeater on the page or a new repeater which you are declaring in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in the comment, that you want to export your repeater that has a checkbox. It is not allowed to export a checkbox to excel and that's why you want to remove the checkbox before exporting.

Here is one way you can do this... just add this in your page and try....

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}
```

Alternatively what if you export your `DataTable` instead of the `repeater` ?

If the above is not working and you want to iterate and then export then here is code...

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=FileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls";

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
       CheckBox chk= item.FindControl("CheckBox") as CheckBox;
       chk.Visible = false;
    }

    Repeater1.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```